# Explosion for a birth and death process

Tags: markov-process, birth-death-process

I understand that for a birth process with rate $\exp(\lambda_n)$, explosion occurs if there are infinitely many individuals born in finite time, which is iff $\sum \frac{1}{\lambda_n}<\infty$.

My question is how do I understand explosion for a birth and death process with rate $\exp(\lambda_n)$ and $\exp(\mu_n)$ respectively. In particular, what does it mean to say "find a birth process that strictly dominated the birth and death process"?

Comment: If your first case is "the birth rates are so high that there is probability $1$ that there are infinitely many individuals born in finite time" then the second might be "the birth rates are so high and so much higher than the death rates that there is a positive probability that there are infinitely many more individuals born in finite time than die in the same time"